# php sum of an sql query and an php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey guys i want a sum of an mysql query and an php variable. Is there a function to do this? Here is what i tried:

```
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
                while ($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
                $Ergebnis = $Menge + $resultarray['Bestand'];
                echo $Ergebnis;
                }
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Edit: I want a sum of an php variable and an mysql query not of two sql tables!!!!

Comment: What is your sql query? There is a `SUM()` function in MySQL that may server this purpose more efficiently, depending on how/what you're using.

Comment: @newfurniturey read my edit

Comment: $Ergebnis .= $Menge + $resultarray['Bestand']; ?

Comment: @2-Stroker @vodich I was looking for something which does this: `$Ergebnis .= $Menge + $resultarray['Bestand'];` because when i use my solution `$Ergebnis` is the same as `$menge`

Comment: I noticed that you use $resultarray['Bestand'] instead of $resultarray3['Bestand']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$menge = '';
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
while ($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
  $menge = $menge + $resultarray3['Bestand'];
}
// result => $menge
```

Answer (score 1):

If  there is only one row  you don't need the `.=`

```
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
            while ($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
            $Ergebnis .= $Menge + $resultarray3['Bestand'];//notice the change on this line
            echo $Ergebnis;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A query to show a result contains SUM(column), so you could use:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT bestand, SUM(bestand) as menge FROM database GROUP BY bestand";
```

And then in PHP

```
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
while ($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    echo $resultarray['bestand'] . ' = ' . $resultarray['menge'];
}
```

Comment: no i want simply do this: `$Ergebnis .= $Menge + $resultarray['Bestand'];` and `$menge is an php variable`

Answer (score 0):

You define `$resultarray3` but then you use `$resultarray` without the three.

```
$Ergebnis = $Menge + $resultarray3['Bestand'];
```